# WordPress: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I try to solve this problem, at Object.user_setting (jscript.js?ver=3.2.0:1894)

here his error message:

```
jscript.js?ver=3.2.0:1894 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at Object.user_setting (jscript.js?ver=3.2.0:1894)
    at admin.php?page=user-settings:1078
user_setting @ jscript.js?ver=3.2.0:1894
(anonymous) @ admin.php?page=user-settings:1078
```

and the code is:

```
        for(var i in _keys) {

            if(_keys[i] == 'layout' || _keys[i] == 'map_layout'  || _keys[i] == 'infobox_layout' || _keys[i] == 'color_scheme' || _keys[i] == 'color_scheme_1' || _keys[i] == 'color_scheme_2' || _keys[i] == 'font_color_scheme') {

                var $elem = $form.find('#asl-'+_keys[i]+'-'+_configs[_keys[i]]);
                $elem[0].checked = true;
                continue;
            }


            var $elem = $form.find('#asl-'+_keys[i]);


            if($elem[0].type == 'checkbox')
                $elem[0].checked = (_configs[_keys[i]] == '0')?false:true;
            else
                $elem.val(_configs[_keys[i]]);
        }
```

Comment: `$form.find('#asl-'+_keys[i])` isn't finding any elements.

Comment: what you mean ?

Comment: The error says that you are trying to access type off of undefined.  The only place you have .type in the logic is in the if, and you are calling it off of `$elem[0]`.  So that means that is undefined.  So that means your selector is not finding any elements